# Is there a way to display Yes or No in a result query insted of 0 or 1?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to make create a query where when I select a row and a column is 0 it shows No, and if 1 it displays Yes.

This is a example table.

```
SELECT * FROM NUMBERS
RESULT:
PRODUCT | HAS
APPLES  | 0
GRAPES  | 1
```

And insted of displaying 1 or 0 it show YES or NO.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use MySQL's `IF` statement

```
SELECT `PRODUCT`, IF(`HAS` = 1, 'Yes', 'No') AS `HAS`
FROM NUMBERS
```

Comment: You could shorten it to `IF(HAS, 'Yes', 'No')`.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can use case statement for this

```
SELECT 
PRODUCT, 
case when `HAS`= 1 then 'YES'
else 'NO' end as `HAS`
FROM NUMBERS
```

Comment: it didnt worked for some reason

Comment: Not sure what is not working for you , but it should work http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4b9e3/1