# While using mysql select query i need the get the column value as Yes/No instead of getting 0/1

Tags: mysql

Column name is modified and the type is tinyint(1).
How to fetch the column value as Yes/No using select query.
And also I have 3 document name in one package while using select query the document name is split into three rows with same package name.

Here is the example for that column value has split into three rows:
Expected Output:

```
name | data
```

`abc  | a,b,c 
 def  | be`

Actual Output:

```
name | data
abc | a
abc | b
abc | c
def | be
```

Here is the code:
`select p.filename,p.version,doc.name from certificate_packages cp join packages p on cp.package_id=p.id left join package_documents pd on p.id=pd.package_id left join documents doc on doc.id=pd.document_id where cp.certificate_id=1099;`

```
[![Attached the screenshot][1]][1]
```

[image: Group_Concat]

[image: Before group by file name]
[image: After group by file name]

Comment: you can write a stored procedure for this...which uses if else statement

Comment: i think your question title and body of question not match .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24246345/is-there-a-way-to-display-yes-or-no-in-a-result-query-insted-of-0-or-1 (btw, you could find it yourself)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL: Split comma separated list into multiple rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936088/mysql-split-comma-separated-list-into-multiple-rows)

Comment: @JYoThI no, he wants to print `a,b,c` if there is some condition and `be` otherwise

Comment: she didn't mention it in body of question . @MichaelO.

Comment: which one is your expected out put title it properly @Priya

Comment: what you tried so far where your struggling ? show us some code .

Comment: @JYoThI Here is the code that the column values are splitted as three rows:

Comment: your expected output is abc  | a,b,c 
 def  | be  is it ? @Priya

Comment: use group_concat

Comment: @JYoThI While giving group concat, it combining all the column values into one single row. Please find above the screenshot attached.

Comment: at the end missing group by filename

Comment: try this select p.filename,p.version,GORUP_CONCAT(doc.name) AS NAME from certificate_packages cp join packages p on cp.package_id=p.id left join package_documents pd on p.id=pd.package_id left join documents doc on doc.id=pd.document_id where cp.certificate_id=1099 gorup by p.filename;

Comment: @JYoThI Some name is missing, please find both screenshot before groupby file name and after groupby filename

Comment: add group by version too like this  gorup by p.filename,p.version

Comment: @JYoThI Same output what i get for after groupby filename result.

Comment: try this select p.filename,p.version,GORUP_CONCAT(doc.name) AS NAME from certificate_packages cp join packages p on cp.package_id=p.id left join package_documents pd on p.id=pd.package_id left join documents doc on doc.id=pd.document_id where cp.certificate_id=1099 p.filename,p.version ;

Comment: i seen your screen shot your missed group_concat on that query

Comment: @JYoThI I added now. Thanks for the solution. finally got it. Thank you so much

Comment: i posted it as answer . mark it with green tick if it is useful . because it's useful for future user reference @Priya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per our comment the final solution is .You need give `gorup_by p.filename,p.version ;` column name like this

```
select p.filename,p.version,GROUP_CONCAT(doc.name) AS name 
from certificate_packages cp 
join packages p 
on cp.package_id=p.id 
left join package_documents pd 
on p.id=pd.package_id 
left join documents doc 
on doc.id=pd.document_id 
where cp.certificate_id=1099 
p.filename,p.version ;
```